# Disabling right click for a folder in a DVD, not allowing copy & paste functions

Tags: dvd, copy-paste, right-click, copy-protection

I have prepared a video DVD (DVD-5) and will be giving it to some of my friends.

However, I wish to disable the right click option for the `VIDEO_TS` folder, so no one can copy the folder or the files inside the folder.

I also do not want to allow Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V options to the `.VOB` files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Windows, you can't do this. Windows Explorer will show the folder and it's contents, unless there are security attributes set that make it inaccessible to the user. However, this would also make it impossible for your friends to play the video, as their accounts wouldn't have access to the files.

Comment: Mac, too, incidentally. It's just a folder. You can't prevent its copying.